# Gitlab CI multistage pipeline: Trigger project pipeline by dynamic variable

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I have created upstream Pipeline, and want to trigger downstream pipeline using variable like this.

```
trigger:
    project: ${my_downstream_project}_1
    main: main
```

This works in new version of gitlab my problem is I can't use variable in project: as previous version doesn't supports variable in place of project name.

Is there any way to trigger project using script and wait for job to be done. and sleep the script until you gett response